# enable/disable textbox on bases of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

So I am trying to enable text box if other option is selected from dropdown list
i.e when i select the other option without clicking any button it shows the textbox
code is listed below with js file but its not working need help with this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#type_').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'other') {
        $('#other_type').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
        $('#other_type').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
</script>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Type : "></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="type_" runat="server"  style="margin-left: 0px">
        <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="other_type" runat="server" style="margin-left: 33px; display:none"  Width="157px"></asp:TextBox>.......
```

Comment: can u add ClientIDMode=Static to your dropdownlist and textbox control?

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap the code with `$(function(){});` to bind the click after the page loads.
You're not properly selecting elements. ASP .NET changes the ID property, so you have to use <%= *ControlName*.ClientID %> to get the generated ID.
Or give a CssClass to the controls.

```
$(function(){
   $('#<%= type_.ClientID %>').change(function () {
      if (this.val() == 'other') {
         $('#<%= other_type.ClientID %>').css('display', 'block');
      }
      else {
         $('#<%= other_type.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
      }
});
```

Comment: not working can you please check does i link the js file perfectly ?